# ImportError: No module named win32com.client (I'm sure I have pywin32 installed)

Tags: python, anaconda, pywin32

This may seem like a repost but none of the other answers for this issue have helped. I am absolutely sure I have pywin32 installed. I first installed it through conda, then when that didn't work I did a pip install of pypiwin32, also to my conda environment. No matter what I try, it always dies on the very first line:

```
from win32com.client import Dispatch
```

and throws:

```
ImportError: No module named win32com.client
```

What could the problem be?

Comment: `import sys` then `print(sys.path)`. Do you have the folder `win32com` in folder 'C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages\win32com` and is folder `C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages` listed in `sys.path`?

Comment: Depending of course on which version of Python you have..

Comment: I have `C:\\Users\\[username]\\AppData\\Local\\Continuum\\Anaconda2\\lib\\site-packages\\win32` and `C:\\Users\\[username]\\AppData\\Local\\Continuum\\Anaconda2\\lib\\site-packages`, is that equivalent? I have the win32com folder in the site-packages folder, but it doesn't appear to be in that path. that could be it.

Comment: Is it possible that there's a mismatch between a 32-bit Python and a 64-bit Pywin32 or *vice versa*?

Comment: I see nothing wrong with what you have. You could always try installing withing anaconda: `$ conda install pywin32`.

Comment: Is there anything from _pywin32_ that works? e.g. `import pywintypes` or `import win32api`? Are you sure that the _Python_ that you installed _pywin32_ on is the one that you launch?

Comment: So after a day, it works now. I have no idea why. Sorry for anyone else having the same problem who found this question.

Answer (score 1):

Which command did you use for the library installation through Conda?
try this command in your terminal and then after a while press the key[y]:

```
conda install -c anaconda pywin32
```